# When submitting extension to Magento2 Marketplace gives error "Error During Installation Command returned non-zero exit code"

Tags: magento2, php

When submitting extension to Magento2 Marketplace gives error "**Error During Installation Command returned non-zero exit code**".

**Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 5.6.30, Magento Platform - 2.0.13 CE
Command: deploy:mode:set production**

While I am able to install and command "**deploy:mode:set production**" showing no error on my end.

Please help me if anyone encountered the same problem.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: It may due to compilation errors. Run setup:di:compile and look for any errors. If so, fix it and move to production.

Comment: I already tried to run setup:di:compile command. But Found no error in this.

Magento marketplace testing extension on "Magento Platform - 2.0.13 CE"
When I install this version on localhost. This gives me same error as i listed in question when run command "deploy:mode:set production". However I didn't install my extension yet on this magento installation.

Comment: Anyone there who can faced the same issue ?

Comment: I am facing same issue, Getting errors from the MarketPlace, however, there are no errors in module.

Did you get solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the extension prevents product and category pages from being cached by Varnish. One possible cause is using **cacheable="false"** in one or more blocks on product and category pages.

Additional resources: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html